# spray set content-type for XML

Tags: xml, scala, header, spray

When trying to send an xml content-type Mime-header

```
sender ! HttpResponse(status = 200, entity = responseBody, headers = List(`Content-Type`(`text/xml`)))
```

I get the error:

```
not found: value text/xml
```

I tried with application/xml which did not work either, application/json works FWIW

Is there some import missing?

Edit: tried to add this

```
import spray.http.MediaTypes._
sender ! HttpResponse(status = 400, entity = responseBody, headers = List(`Content-Type`(`application/xml`)))
```

this gave the following error:

```
Explicitly set response header 'Content-Type: application/xml' is 
ignored, the response Content-Type is set via the response's HttpEntity!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import spray.http.HttpEntity    
sender ! HttpResponse(status = 200, entity = httpEntity(`application/xml`,responseBody))
```

relevant documentation

http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-http/#content-type-header